# How to get json data from web api to android application?

Tags: php, android, json, retrofit2, webapi

I wrote a web api to get data from database and convert it into json using php. For testing purposes it is on localhost. How do I get that json data to my android application and display it in recyclerview? I tried retrofit but reponse always failed.

```
private void fetchDetails(){
        Retrofit retrofit=refinstance.getRetrofitInstance();

        GetDataService getDataService=retrofit.create(GetDataService.class);

        Call<List<DataModel>> call=getDataService.getAllData();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<DataModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<DataModel>> call, Response<List<DataModel>> response) {
                    List<DataModel> dlist=response.body();

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,dlist));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<DataModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide some more details or your code

Comment: I updated the question please review @satuser

Comment: also please add the error message and GetDataService class code

Comment: @satuser Since i added toast. The main activity displays toast with "Error" message

Comment: replace toast to Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); or keep a breakpoint inside OnFailure() method and get the error message from logcat